# Is there a way to loop through an array in React using useState?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, use-state

I have an **array of images**

```
image: [interiorDesignOne, interiorDesignTwo, interiorDesignThree],
```

and **state** like these

```
 const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);
```

I then access the correct image using the **index** in my JSX like these

```
   <img
      src={image[imageIndex]}
      alt="Project Image"
      className="project-image cursor"
    />
```

I want to create a sort of slide functionality that **changes the image index every 5 seconds**. My initial approach was to add + 1 to the state each time but it gets to four then my HTML explodes.

*Not working*

```
 const changeShownImage = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (imageIndex === project.images.length) {
        setImageIndex((prev) => prev - 1);
      }
      setImageIndex((prev) => prev + 1);
      changeShownImage();
    }, 5000);
  };
```

I want it in such away that if I reach the end of the array I go back to 0 (The beginning).

Comment: Just use this setImageIndex((imageIndex+1)% image.length); inside your timer.

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-17-forked-x4ezsr , you need to add a condition if the index is equal to `array.length - 1`, if so then set the `imageIndex` back to `0` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **setInterval()** instead of setTimeout()

```
 const changeShownImage = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setImageIndex(prev => prev === (project.images.length - 1 ) ? 0 : prev + 1;
      );
    }, 5000);
  };
```

Comment: Why is setInterval better than setTimeout

Comment: setTimeout allows us to run a function once after the interval of time. setInterval allows us to run a function repeatedly, starting after the interval of time. So setInterval makes your code more readable and gives a clear purpose of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes start at zero. `imageIndex === project.images.length - 1` should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about you add the length check within the setImageIndex function as well. Try something like this:

```
setImageIndex(prev => {
    return prev === project.images.length ? 0 : prev + 1;
});
```